# Invoking a Trigger after a time span

Tags: apex, trigger

I know that triggers are usually invoked by DML events, click of buttons etc. but I was wondering if the following functionality is possible:

I am trying to change a Lead Status to 'Returning to Marketing' if the record's last activity date is older than 2 weeks. Is there any way I can achieve this without having to automatically update all the leads in my org each day to check for the condition described above?

Comment: Time based workflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at `Time Based Workflow`. On Step 3 of setting up your `Workflow Rule`, click the <kbd>Add Time Trigger</kbd> button. You can then set it 14 days after `Lead: My Date Field`.

[image: Step 3 Screenshot]

I think, though, for `LastActivityDate`, you may have trouble crafting appropriate trigger conditions. It should be pretty straightforward to create a batch:

```
public with sharing class LeadActivityBatch
    implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable
{
    @TestVisible static Datetime threshold = Datetime.now().addDays(-14);
    public static final String STATUS = 'Return to Marketing';
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([
            SELECT Id FROM Lead WHERE LastActivityDate < :threshold
        ]);
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<SObject> scope)
    {
        for (SObject record : scope) record.put(Lead.Status, STATUS);
        update scope;
        // proper error handling omitted for brevity
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) { }

    public void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. There is only one issue with the above implementation. On the last line  'Database.executeBatch(this);' triggers an error as the Apex Compiler doesn't understand the 'this' syntax apparently. I don't have much understanding of the batch classes, but I'm assuming that 'this' stands for the current object, which in this case being the equivalent to 'new LeadActivityBatch()'. However, how would I ensure that not that only one batch is executing at a time and are there any recursivity issues with this implementation?

Comment: Ah, none of the methods are supposed to be `static` (just the properties), my mistake. @Marc

Comment: Thanks for the update. But I made the changes and I set the time to 0 hours after the trigger is evoked but the batch class doesn't seem to execute. at all. Is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: It's either or...they are not compatible with each other. If you actually have a field to trigger on, just use WFR with a `Time Trigger`. I don't think you can with `LastActivityDate` though, in which case you should schedule the batch to run each day, or perhaps multiple times per day if you want more frequency.

Comment: I can choose the time trigger to be dependent on the LastActivityDate, anyway  I looked in the log and the workflow seemed to be executing properly and I tried to add some debug statements on the batch class but I couldn t see any. Are the batch classes executing under a different name space? Or more exactly how do you debug them accordingly?

Comment: The workflow and batch are completely separate solutions. If you get wfr running, you don't need batch, and vice versa. Yes you can base time triggers on it but what criteria do you use for the rule itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41161/discussion-between-adrian-larson-and-marc-zaharescu).

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the steps:
1. Create schedular class for daily run.
2. Create an apex class to fetch the records based on the last edited date.
3. Update the status and perform DML.

Also, Its better to use apex class than using batch class here because:
You are making just one query and and one DML.