# Disadvantage To Using Batch?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

[This answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126873/evoking-a-trigger-after-a-time-span#126881) got me wondering, is there a *disadvantage* to using a `Batchable` for simple scheduled functionality, as opposed to executing the functionality purely via `Schedulable`?

> Its [sic] better to use apex class than using batch class here because: You are making just one query and and one DML.

The most obvious advantage of using a batch is scalability when data volume grows. However, are there any specific disadvantages to using a "light batch"?

Some simplifying assumptions might make this question more useful:

- Data Volume: < 5k records
- Daily Scheduled Batches: ~12
- Only one field is being updated

  - The value is uniformly applied

**I am looking specifically for disadvantages to using a batch.**

---

Simple example:

**Batch**

```
public with sharing class DemonstrationBatch
    implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable
{
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context)
    {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Lead]);
    }
    public static void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<SObject> scope)
    {
        for (SObject record : scope)
            record.put(Lead.Status, 'Demonstration');
        update scope;
    }
    public static void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) { }

    public static void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
}
```

**Job**

```
public with sharing class DemonstrationJob implements Schedulable
{
    public static void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id FROM Lead];
        for (Lead lead : leads) lead.Status = 'Demonstration';
        update leads;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the scheduled job: If there is a badly implemented trigger recursion single static boolean on `Lead`, the triggers will never execute for records 201+

Comment: Right, good point. Score one more for the batch. I'm trying to see if there is any justification for the claim that batch should be avoided though. @crop

Comment: the only time I ever regretted using a batch was when I didn't implement the `finish()` logic correctly for detecting limits exceptions :-)

Comment: Daily scheduled batches is 50. That's the equivalent of having a batch job scheduled to run approximately every 30 minutes within the availability of system resources. Considering that a batch can implement the schedulable interface, aren't you really comparing peaches with nectarines? Seems to me you're asking the wrong question. Why not ask what you're losing by not using queuebles instead of either batch or schedulables? That would seem to me to be a more "all encompassing" solution for the task you describe.

Comment: The main issue is the contention that the choice to use a batch instead of a more vanilla approach is a mistake. The numbers were chosen fairly arbitrarily, I just wanted to make sure the number of batches was <100. Perhaps ~12 would be more reasonable scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volume is key. At the volumes you're talking about, and with the frequency, it doesn't really matter, *unless* your user is waiting on the results of the batchable. Basically, there's a maximum number of records you can process per execute call, and there's usually an intra-batch delay that may last for several seconds.

This means that some Queueable that could finish in 1 second flat might take Batchable upwards of 10-20 seconds (or more, on some heavily loaded servers), plus the time needed to run the start method. This can make the experience uncomfortably slow if users are waiting on the results.

For back-end processes where timing isn't critical, choose whichever you prefer. The difference between batchable, queuable, and schedulable classes is fairly insignificant as long as (a) any of them can complete their task before the next one starts, and (b) there's no user waiting on the results of the processing.

Salesforce.com basically says the same thing: the lightweight processes uses fewer resources, so is more friendly to the servers. This is, of course, why we have governor limits. I'm pretty sure that they'd prefer that everyone ditch the batchable interface and go with Queueable, because of the obvious performance benefits that it'd give everyone in a multi-tenant architecture, but there are times when batchable is necessary, such as processing 50,000,000 rows of data.

I'd say that you should probably prefer directly modifying records in schedulable/queueable classes when designing new services, because there is a general performance benefit to the overall system, but I would also say that if your current batchable process is working, and not handling too much data, it's not worth redesigning the code to be queueable if you already have a working implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a method to schedule batch: System.scheduleBatch.
If you need to schedule batch for a one time execution (after a definite number of minutes from now) then you could just use this method and even not to implement Schedulable interface.

Contrary, if you need some logic to be executed on scheduled basis, you always need to implement Schedulable inferface or use some UniversalScheduler to schedule any batchable class.

I would say if the amount of records is less than 200 use only Schedulable.

If the amount of records is less than 200 or you just have to run one SOQL query or perform simple DML operation on less than 200 records then there is no need of Batchable.

There are no specific disadvantages to using a "light batch". You could use batch having one chunk, but I guess it would use more Salesforce resources in such a case.

Comment: I'm not sure what scheduling has to do with my initial question. This post reads mostly like a tangent until the last paragraph.