# Evoking an Apex batch class from a Time-Dependent Workflow Action

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I am trying to call an apex batch class after a set period of time. I was thinking of using Time-Dependent Workflow Actions to achieve this, but how would I make the batch class call?

Comment: You can use the apex scheduler to set the batch for a specific date or time.

Comment: Yes I know that but the time is dependent on the last update of a specific field

Comment: This is just [this question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126873/invoking-a-trigger-after-a-time-span) again, no? I have updated my example there.

Comment: @Adrian yes it is related with the previous question.  I don't fully understand how is the batch class being evoked by the time-based trigger. Could you please share your understanding on this thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic mistake that led to your question is that when you use `static` methods, there is no instance in scope and hence no reference to `this`.

**Works**

```
public class MyClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable
{
    // Batchable implementation
    public void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
}
```

**Doesn't Work**

```
public class MyClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable
{
    // Batchable implementation
    public static void execute(SchedulableContext context)
    {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
}
```